# Not Build plugin gradle

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

Build file 'AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\build.gradle.kts'

Please help me to decide this problem. i download the file gradle 8.0, but program Android studio not build gradle. why is this happening? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEMlD.png)

Answer (score 0):

check gradle wrappper properties
and add this one

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
```

which u are showing is upper gradle
it some look like this

```
buildscript {

    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.0'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.42' apply false
//    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.14' apply false
//    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version '2.9.2' apply false
}
```

and sync project online dont do offline check internet also